# BeautifulSoup in Python not parsing right

Tags: python, html, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am running Python 2.7.5 and using the built-in html parser for what I am about to describe.

The task I am trying to accomplish is to take a chunk of html that is essentially a recipe. Here is an example.

`html_chunk = "<h1>Miniature Potato Knishes</h1><p>Posted by bettyboop50 at recipegoldmine.com May 10, 2001</p><p>Makes about 42 miniature knishes</p><p>These are just yummy for your tummy!</p><p>3 cups mashed potatoes (about<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2 very large potatoes)<br>2 eggs, slightly beaten<br>1 large onion, diced<br>2 tablespoons margarine<br>1 teaspoon salt (or to taste)<br>1/8 teaspoon black pepper<br>3/8 cup Matzoh meal<br>1 egg yolk, beaten with 1 tablespoon water</p><p>Preheat oven to 400 degrees F.</p><p>Sauté diced onion in a small amount of butter or margarine until golden brown.</p><p>In medium bowl, combine mashed potatoes, sautéed onion, eggs, margarine, salt, pepper, and Matzoh meal.</p><p>Form mixture into small balls about the size of a walnut. Brush with egg yolk mixture and place on a well-greased baking sheet and bake for 20 minutes or until well browned.</p>"`

The goal is to separate out the header, junk, ingredients, instructions, serving, and number of ingredients.

Here is my code that accomplishes that

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def list_to_string(list):
   joined = ""
   for item in list:
      joined += str(item)
   return joined

def get_ingredients(soup):
   for p in soup.find_all('p'):
      if p.find('br'):
         return p

def get_instructions(p_list, ingredient_index):
   instructions = []
   instructions += p_list[ingredient_index+1:]
   return instructions

def get_junk(p_list, ingredient_index):
   junk = []
   junk += p_list[:ingredient_index]
   return junk

def get_serving(p_list):
   for item in p_list:
      item_str = str(item).lower()
      if ("yield" or "make" or "serve" or "serving") in item_str:
         yield_index = p_list.index(item)
         del p_list[yield_index]
         return item

def ingredients_count(ingredients):
   ingredients_list = ingredients.find_all(text=True)
   return len(ingredients_list)

def get_header(soup):
   return soup.find('h1')

def html_chunk_splitter(soup):
   ingredients = get_ingredients(soup)
   if ingredients == None:
      error = 1
      header = ""
      junk_string = ""
      instructions_string = ""
      serving = ""
      count = ""
   else:
      p_list = soup.find_all('p')
      serving = get_serving(p_list)
      ingredient_index = p_list.index(ingredients)
      junk_list = get_junk(p_list, ingredient_index)
      instructions_list = get_instructions(p_list, ingredient_index)
      junk_string = list_to_string(junk_list)
      instructions_string = list_to_string(instructions_list)
      header = get_header(soup)
      error = ""
      count = ingredients_count(ingredients)
   return (header, junk_string, ingredients, instructions_string, 
   serving, count, error)
```

It works well except in situations where I have chunks that contain strings like `"Sauté"` because `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_chunk)` causes Sauté to turn into SautÃ© and this is a problem because I have a huge csv file of recipes like the html_chunk and I'm trying to structure all of them nicely and then get the output back into a database. I tried checking it SautÃ© comes out right using this [html previewer](http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/) and it still comes out as SautÃ©. I don't know what to do about this.

What's stranger is that when I do what BeautifulSoup's documentation shows

```
BeautifulSoup("Sacr&eacute; bleu!")
# <html><head></head><body>Sacré bleu!</body></html>
```

I get

```
# Sacr├⌐ bleu!
```

But my colleague tried that on his Mac, running from terminal, and he got exactly what the documentation shows.

I really appreciate all your help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running the script in a terminal/cmd, is your file with UTF-8 encoding, # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- is at the top of your file?

Comment: Where are you getting `SacrÃ© bleu!`? In the browser? In the terminal?

Comment: I am doing this on a PC running Windows 7. I am using Wing IDE 101 4.1 (the free one). At first I thought that might be the problem, so I just fired up IDLE itself and tried it out there and I got the same results. I actually don't know much about encoding, but I pretty much copied and pasted that from [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup). I am getting `SacrÃ© bleu!` in IDLE and Wing IDE, so the terminal, I suppose.

Comment: Well do you have the # -- coding: utf-8 -- at the top?

Comment: What do you mean? There's no file. I'm just copied and pasted that from the the [link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup). While I am doing all this because it will run through a file of mine, it is a CSV and I don't know how to check encoding. At the top of what?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the output in IDLE. On Windows, it's possible that it tries to display the character according to the Windows-cp1252 encoding (almost the same as latin 1). See what you get in the end product you're trying to make (be it a website or a software).

Comment: What version is your beautiful soup.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a parsing problem; it is about encoding, rather.

Whenever working with text which might contain non-ASCII characters (or in Python programs which contain such characters, e.g. in comments or docstrings), you should put a coding cookie in the first or - after the shebang line - second line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

... and make sure this matches your file encoding (with vim: `:set fenc=utf-8`).

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup tries to guess the encoding, sometimes it makes a mistake, however you can specify the encoding by adding the `from_encoding` parameter: 
for example

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, from_encoding="UTF-8")
```

The encoding is usually available in the header of the webpage