# Python BeautifulSoup Ampersand issue Mac vs. Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, html, linux, macos, beautifulsoup

I've read that BeautifulSoup has problems with ampersands (&) which are not strictly correct in HTML but still interpreted correctly by most browsers. However weirdly I'm getting different behaviour on a Mac system and on a Ubuntu system, both using bs4 version 4.3.2:

```
html='<td>S&P500</td>'
s=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

On the Ubuntu system s is equal to:

```
<td>S&amp;P500;</td>
```

Notice the added semicolon at the end which is a real problem

On the mac system:

```
<html><head></head><body>S&amp;P500</body></html>
```

Never mind the html/head/body tags, I can deal with that, but notice S&P 500 is correctly interpreted this time, without the added ";".

Any idea what's going on? How to make cross-platform code without resorting to an ugly hack? Thanks a lot,

Comment: Broken `<td>S&amp;P500;</td>` for me on both Debian and Mac OS X, version 4.3.2 installed by `pip` just now. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

First I can't reproduce the mac results using python2.7.1 and beautifulsoup4.3.2, that is I am getting the extra semicolon on all systems.

The easy fix is a) use strictly valid HTML, or b) add a space after the ampersand. Chances are you can't change the source, and if you could parse out and replace these in python you wouldn't be needing BeautifulSoup ;)

So the problem is that the BeautifulSoupHTMLParser first converts `S&P500` to `S&P500;` because it assumes `P500` is the character name and you just forgot the semicolon.

Then later it reparses the string and finds `&P500;`. Now it doesn't recognize `P500` as a valid name and converts the `&` to `&amp;` without touching the rest.

Here is a stupid monkeypatch **only to demonstrate my point**. I don't know the inner workings of BeautifulSoup well enough to propose a proper solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder._htmlparser import BeautifulSoupHTMLParser
from bsp.dammit import EntitySubstitution

def handle_entityref(self, name):
    character = EntitySubstitution.HTML_ENTITY_TO_CHARACTER.get(name)
    if character is not None:
        data = character
    else:
        # Previously was
        # data = "&%s;" % name
        data = "&%s" % name
    self.handle_data(data)

html = '<td>S&P500</td>'

# Pre monkeypatching
# <td>S&amp;P500;</td>
print(BeautifulSoup(html))

BeautifulSoupHTMLParser.handle_entityref = handle_entityref

# Post monkeypatching    
# <td>S&amp;P500</td>
print(BeautifulSoup(html))
```

Hopefully someone more versed in bs4 can give you a proper solution, good luck.

Comment: thanks, useful - there does seem to be different behaviour b/w systems, see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515986/beautifulsoup-in-python-not-parsing-right?rq=1)

Comment: It's very possible, but that link in particular appears to be an encoding issue. Ampersand is in the ascii set, so those issues shouldn't affect this example.

Comment: I guess brute force would be to create a dictionary of ascii characters and their numerical code / shortcut code - then do search for all ampersand characters, if they're not followed by characters which make a code, replace the & by &amp;

Comment: That is what this does, python's HTMLParser matches something like `&[^\s]+` as entityref and passes it to the handle_entityref function. Then we check if its in the dictionary using HTML_ENTITY_TO_CHARACTER.get(name) and ignore it if we don't find it in the dictionary.